# Extract optimal value of controls from nloptr in R

Tags: r, optimization, nlopt

I am fairly new to R, and I wrote a function that I am optimizing using the nloptr package in R. The optimization itself works and converges to a solution, however it is presented as a list. Is there anyway to extract the last the "optimal value of controls" in the last lane of the output (shown below):

Call:

```
nloptr(x0 = x0, eval_f = Profit, opts = opts)
Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 
NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or 
xtol_abs (above) was reached. )
Number of Iterations....: 103200 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-12    maxeval: 1e+06 
Number of inequality constraints:  0 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Optimal value of objective function:  -5363.8525727957 
Optimal value of controls: 0.2736403 9.450551 1.122106 0.4090966
```

Comment: Use `str(your_object)` to see the structure of the final. To your case you have to find the name o the element of the list printed with `Optimal Value controls` and then extract it with `object[["name"]][<element>]`. Without a reproducible example is hart to help you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
res<-nloptr(...)
```

`res$solution` will give the vector of optimal value controls,

`res$objective` will give you the value of objective function.